# Recursive select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I have an issue I just can't get my head around. I know what I want, just simply can't get it out on the screen.
What I have is a table looking like this:

```
Id, PK UniqueIdentifier, NotNull
Name, nvarchar(255), NotNull
ParentId, UniqueIdentifier, Null
```

ParentId have a FK to Id.

What I want to accomplish is to get a flat list of all the id's below the Id I pass in.

example:

```
1   TestName1    NULL
2   TestName2    1
3   TestName3    2
4   TestName4    NULL
5   TestName5    1
```

The tree would look like this:

```
-1
  -> -2
       -> -3
  -> -5
-4
```

If I now ask for 4, I would only get 4 back, but if I ask for 1 I would get 1, 2, 3 and 5.
If I ask for 2, I would get 2 and 3 and so on.

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction. My brain is fried so I appreciate all help I can get.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
declare @T table(
  Id int primary key,
  Name nvarchar(255) not null,
  ParentId int)

insert into @T values
(1,   'TestName1',    NULL),
(2,   'TestName2',    1),
(3,   'TestName3',    2),
(4,   'TestName4',    NULL),
(5,   'TestName5',    1)

declare @Id int = 1

;with cte as
(  
  select T.*
  from @T as T
  where T.Id = @Id
  union all
  select T.*
  from @T as T
    inner join cte as C
      on T.ParentId = C.Id
)
select *
from cte
```

Result

```
Id          Name                 ParentId
----------- -------------------- -----------
1           TestName1            NULL
2           TestName2            1
5           TestName5            1
3           TestName3            2
```

Comment: This is the way I'd do it, recursing Down the tree from the node being searched from.

Comment: This works great! seems to be fast and accomplish just what I want. Thanks very much for the help! Finally I get somewhere again :)

Comment: @Dems +1. Recursing down is the way I want! :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a working example:

```
declare @t table (id int, name nvarchar(255), ParentID int)

insert @t values
(1,   'TestName1',    NULL),
(2,   'TestName2',    1   ),
(3,   'TestName3',    2   ),
(4,   'TestName4',    NULL),
(5,   'TestName5',    1   );

; with rec as
        (
        select  t.name
        ,       t.id as baseid
        ,       t.id
        ,       t.parentid
        from    @t t
        union all
        select  t.name
        ,       r.baseid
        ,       t.id
        ,       t.parentid
        from    rec r
        join    @t t
        on      t.ParentID = r.id
        )
select  *
from    rec
where   baseid = 1
```

You can filter on `baseid`, which contains the start of the tree you're querying for.

Comment: This recurses up the tree, for the whole tree, then filters for the wanted records. Is it not 'better' to start at the required node and then recurse down?

Comment: @Dems: The optimizer will move the where clause into the CTE, so it'll execute as you suggest.  It seemed clearer to move the start condition outside the recursive machinery.

Comment: Apologies, mis-read it, this does indeed recurse Down the tree, and so the WHERE clause does indeed prevent uneccesary calcualtion.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
WITH RecQry AS
(
    SELECT *
      FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.*
      FROM MyTable a INNER JOIN RecQry b
        ON a.ParentID = b.Id
)
SELECT *
  FROM RecQry
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article about [Hierarchy ID models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx).  It goes right from the start of the data right through to the query designs.

Also, you could use a [Recursive Query using a Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the first article you link to actually uses Common Table Expressions for recursive queries (even though it doesn't come out and mention the fact).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for would be to write a recursive query using a Common Table Expression:

[MSDN - Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)