# Dealing with a lot of columns in a recursive cte

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I want to retrive sets of hierarchical structured data from a table and I found a solution for sql-server in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649446/recursive-select-in-sql). Porting the solution found there to oracle dosnt quite work. As it seems i have to specify an alias list in my case as follows:

```
WITH cte ( ID ) AS (
  SELECT  T.ID
  FROM SomeTable T
  WHERE T.ID = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  T.ID
  FROM SomeTable T
  INNER JOIN cte C
  ON T.BASE_ID = C.ID
)
SELECT *
from cte;
```

The Problem i have now is that `SomeTable` has 200 columns and i need quite a lot of them. I cant just replace the selects in the with-statement with `SELECT T.*` as i then get the `ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns` error unless i add all columns to the alias list (which makes sense). That of course would be rather unwieldy for the given table.

Is there a way for oracle-sql to tell the cte to use all columns without the need to explicitly list them all?

Comment: *Porting the solution found there to oracle dosnt quite work.*: this query would probably work in oracle, what issues are you having with it?

Comment: "*without the need to explicitly list them all*" no there isn't

Comment: A convenient way to produce a SELECT on many fields is to use DBA_TAB_COLUMNS table to produce the fieldlist. Something like that : SELECT column_name FROM DBA_ALL_COLUMNS WHERE table_name='SomeTable' ORDER BY column_id. Then you can just use string aggregation function to directly copy/paste the result in your big SELECT query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the columns for the recursive definition, just join them afterwards:

```
select t.*
from cte join
     t
     on cte.id = t.id
```

Comment: i gues that one was to obvious for me... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Same number of columns required in order to perform a `UNION ALL`.

Look at Oracle reference: [The UNION ALL, INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I assume SOMETABLE  has  200 columns.
I have created a With Clause having two expressions.
1st expression cte1 which will have all the columns.
Second expression cte2 gets the data using 1st expression(cte1).

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT T.*
FROM SOMETABLE T
WHERE T.ID = 1),
cte2 AS(SELECT C.*
FROM SOMETABLE T
INNER JOIN cte1 C ON T.BASE_ID = C.ID
)
SELECT * FROM cte2;
```

I hope this helps to get all the columns.